Microsoft List text string validation
I'm whipping up a List and am hoping to use a number field to force any user to only input two single digit numbers, a decimal, then two single digits - eg "12.34". I feel like its a dumb question but I'm new to all this. Any advice would be appreciated.
Cheers
G

You can set the number of decimals combined with setting a minimum and maximum allowed value which should be enough to limit the values that can be entered as you require - however, anything above 99.00 won't be possible using this way.

